# "Leads Resources"

Tags: meaning

> If you have leads resources of export clients and desire to supply leads resources to Alibaba.com, please join us as a Lead Affiliate.

I could not understand the meaning of "leads resources" clearly in the above sentence. Does it mean the leading export companies in Turkey?
If so, why **"lead"**is plural?

Comment: I can't understand it either.   It doesn't appear to have been written by a native speaker.  In future alway indicate the source.  Here it is https://www.eworldtrade.com/become-a-partner/  Even the title of that site is wrong "Become a partners" I'm going to vote to close this, as there is no possible answer except "that is incorrect English"

Comment: they could be talking about **sales leads** which are ["a person or business who may eventually become a client"](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sales-lead.asp#:~:text=A%20sales%20lead%20is%20a,parties%2C%20and%20other%20marketing%20efforts.)...